# Make contenteditable div : fixed width and using replace mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed-width

My goal is to make fixed-width text editor where every line has different specs.

For this I need to ....

Make contenteditable div : fixed width

Next is it possible when editing to replace the character rather than insert it.

I also want to limit the number of characters allowed. Here is how I do it, but if there is a better way ? (this makes it artificially fixed-width)

```
document.addEventListener("beforeinput", function(e) {
    console.log("input event fired"+e.data);
    if (e.data != null && e.target.innerText.length +e.data.length > 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}, false);
```

---

my experiment so far :

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 4px;
    font-family: monospace;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.row {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function  get_caret(node){
        var selection = document.getSelection();
        if (!selection || !node) return 0;
        selection.collapseToEnd();
        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        const clone = range.cloneRange();
        clone.selectNodeContents(node);
        clone.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        return clone.toString().length;
    }

    function set_caret(node,pos)    {
        node.focus();
        const textNode = node.firstChild;
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(textNode, pos);
        range.setEnd(textNode, pos);
        const sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }

    function listen() { 
        document.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            text = e.target.innerText
            size = e.target.style.width
            size = + size.substring(0,size.length-2)
            console.log(size)
            if ( text.length > size) {
                // e.preventDefault();
                ix = text.indexOf(e.data)
                if (ix >= size) ix = size - 1
                console.log(ix,':', text)
                e.target.innerText = text.substring(0, ix+1) + text.substring(ix+2)
                set_caret(e.target,ix+1)
                console.log(text.substring(0, ix+1) +':'+ text.substring(ix+2))
                return;
            }
        }, false);
    }   

    function setup(cfg){
        let root = document.getElementById(cfg.root)
        console.log(root)
        for (row of cfg.specs){
            let rdiv = document.createElement('div');
            rdiv.setAttribute('class','row');
            root.appendChild(rdiv)
            for (col of row){
                cdiv = document.createElement('div');
                cdiv.setAttribute('class','col');
                cdiv.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
                cdiv.style.width = col + 'ch'
                cdiv.style.height = '1em'
                rdiv.appendChild(cdiv)

            }
        }
    }

    let cfg = {
        'root' : 'container',
        'specs' : [
            [2,4,5],
            [3,6,2]
        ]
    }

window.addEventListener('load', 
  function() { 
    setup(cfg);
    listen();
  }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id=container></div>    


</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say: 
"Next is it possible when editing to replace the character rather than insert it."
Do you want to replace a certain input character from the user after typing?

Comment: editing to work in REPLACE mode :  1|23 =5=> 15|3 , instead of 15|23

Comment: Why not use a `textarea` html element instead of a contenteditable `div`? `textarea` element accepts a `cols` attribute that you can use to make it fixed width. It also accepts `minlength` and `maxlength` attributes to control the number of characters. Also what do you mean by "where every line has different specs"?

Comment: different widths of the cols on every line